# relative import error in python and where can find python module source code

Tags: python, python-import

I'm quite new to python. Though I understand the basic data types,control flow ,etc, I still feel a lit bit difficult  from top-level view.

One of these questions is `relative import`.
I have a piece of code from a book trying to implement queue structure using python. When I run the code I got error from the import, 
"ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package".

**Here is line of the import:**

```
from ..exceptions import Empty
```

I'm now in my working project folder. 
My question is how can  I make adjustment to this line to make the whole piece of code work?
I guess this "exceptions" module is made by the author not the built-in module and somehow the author does not include the module in the current folder.
Where can I find python built-in module source code so I can take a look?

**My system is ubuntu**

Thank you.

Comment: For your side question "Where can I find Python built-in module source code": You can either [download the source](https://www.python.org/download/source/) or [browse it online](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/) (change that `default` to `2.7` or `3.3` or whatever if you want a specific version). The C source to binary modules is in `Modules`, the Python source to pure-Python modules is in `Lib`, and the C source to most of the builtin types and functions are in `Objects` or `Python` (for `bltinmodule.c` and `sysmodule.c`).

Answer (score 1):

These are *explicit relative imports*. That syntax means that the file where that line of code resides is trying to `import` the `Empty` module (I'm making an educated guess about that, not seeing the actual dir structure, although it's unusual for a module to have a capital leading letter -- generally that's reserved for classes) from the `exceptions` subfolder which resides in its parent directory.

See the [Module: Packages doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more info, including a specific folder-structure example with relative imports.

The book really should've presented the code in a self-contained directory structure -- say, a *git* repo you could clone -- where these intra-package dependencies will just work. It's unlikely to be related to your system install if it's stock (although certainly one can set *PYTHONPATH* and other such methods that could affect the environment).

What does the module structure look like?

I'd also recommend you look into [*virtualenv*](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in order to sandbox your Python environments. (Although for custom code, you *may* also need to run a local *Pypi* server or similar, although there are other options - see @abarnert's comment below). It wouldn't on its own help this particular issue, but it's a good idea in general for keeping projects and their various package requirements isolated.

Comment: You don't really need to run a custom PyPI server; to install a custom `foo`, you can just cd into the `foo` directory and `pip install --upgrade .` instead of `pip install --upgrade foo`.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking more of the operational mode where you run a local Pypi server and add `--extra-index <url>` to the `pip` invocation and include the custom module in the *requirements* file. But it's interesting that this is also an option.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a more flexible and powerful solution, but the quick&dirty solution is sometimes useful—and may be a lot easier for someone just getting started. (Maybe I'm a little _too_ worried about scaring novices away from `virtualenv`, but it's always sad when someone who clearly should have been using it didn't because they thought it sounded too complicated…)

Comment: True, it's always a fine line between functionality/power and barrier to entry.